# HTML/CSS - Hide Scrollbar Until Tab is Chosen and Content is Displayed

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am currently building a website and I do not want a scroll bar to be shown until a tab is clicked and the content is shown. Currently, when I load the page, a scroll bar immediately appears. The reason why is obvious: the content in the tabs has already loaded but is not shown until the relevant tab is clicked on. Makes sense. I want to remove that scroll bar until the tab is clicked on, regardless of the content having already loaded.

Here's a screen-grab of the scroll bars and the content not being loaded.

[Content loaded but not shown; scroll bars active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX6Ca.jpg)

Here's the relevant code:

HTML

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#still" data-toggle="tab">Still</a></li>
        <li><a href="#people" data-toggle="tab">People</a></li>
        <li><a href="#product" data-toggle="tab">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portraits" data-toggle="tab">Portraits</a></li>
        <li><a href="#street" data-toggle="tab">Street</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#iphone" data-toggle="tab">iPhone</a></li>
 </ul>

    <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div id="people" class="tab-pane fade active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <img src="portfolio/people/thumbnails/IMG_1632_thumb.jpg">
                    <img src="portfolio/people/thumbnails/IMG_2980_thumb.jpg">                       
                    <img src="portfolio/people/thumbnails/IMG_5960_thumb.jpg">
                    <img src="portfolio/people/thumbnails/IMG_6443_thumb.jpg">
                    <img src="portfolio/people/thumbnails/IMG_6723_thumb.jpg">                     
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 /*apply styling to the tab-content*/
.tab-content
{  
    padding-top: 20px;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;    
}

/*apply style to the rows in the tab-content*/
.tab-content .row
{
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
```

I will admit that there may not be a way to do this without external libraries, but I thought I'd still ask just in case.

Comment: Try adding overflow:hidden to ".tab-content" before content shown and add "overflow: visible" when the tab is clicked

Comment: Do you know about the overflow property? Maybe [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) will help

Comment: @flosommerfeld Overflow knowledge helped immensely! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript to switch a tab you can add css properties on the same function.

First you say the body has `body{ overflow: hidden }` on default. On tab switch function you can add this line: `document.body.style.overflow = "auto";` to show the scroll bar